# How to deploy using bit torrent to servers?

Tags: deployment, architecture, server

I've only heard about this, that few game companies and facebook use this approach.

I understand concept. But I am concerned how to make it secure. From my experience anyone can connect to torrent as long as they can get the link to torrent server.

Say I have 100 servers and I want to update the code to them, some deployed on cloud and some owned personally, spread around the globe. How can I setup bitTorrent based deployment.

Comment: https://torrentfreak.com/facebook-uses-bittorrent-and-they-love-it-100625/

Comment: You can read up on and experiment with [Murder, developed by Twitter](https://github.com/lg/murder). It no longer maintains it, but the project was created to solve this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I might guess that places are using BT (Resilio?) [Sync](https://getsync.com/), or some sort of in-house version thereof for security's sake.  It can be restricted to a LAN, or a set of IPs, and depending on the security requirements, additional encryption could be used outside of Sync.  Of course, there are open source alternatives like [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), that might be preferable if you want to be able to audit the code before use.

I've used Sync to share client-side git repositories between a couple of working machines.  I see no fundamental reason why it couldn't be used on the other end to disseminate live code or compiled binaries.  Not sure if it's the best system, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: thanks for sharing this, didn't know about Sync or Syncthing

Answer (score 1):

The BitTorrent protocol offers everything you need to make this private. Create a torrent marked as private (disables DHT and non-tracker peer discovery methods), and set up your own tracker server over HTTPS. Configure client to require encryption. With this setup, someone who can inspect your network traffic shouldn't be able to figure out the torrent hash. Without knowing the hash they can't request that your clients send them any data. So just keep peer discovery under lock and key, and use encryption.